# Python not able to find tests when test files are in different module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I have a directory structure like below

```
horizontalupgrade
  common/
    __init__.py
    upgradestate.py
  tests/
    common/
      __init__.py
      testupgradestate.py
```

Content of `testupgradestate.py`

```
import unittest
from upgradestate import UpgradeState

class UpgradeStateTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print "Setup Called"

    def test_copy(self):
        u = UpgradeState("")
        print "test_copy Called"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(UpgradeStateTest)
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite)
```

But on trying to execute the tests python is not able to find the tests

```
(venv) dmanna-a01:horizontalupgrade dmanna$ python -m unittest discover  -v

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

But if I make my directory structure like below

```
horizontalupgrade
  common/
    __init__.py
    upgradestate.py
    testupgradestate.py
```

Then the tests are running fine

```
(venv) dmanna-a01:horizontalupgrade dmanna$ python -m unittest discover  -v
test_copy (common.testupgradestate.UpgradeStateTest) ... Setup Called
test_copy Called
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong? How can I make the tests run from a different test package?

- Python - 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `__init__.py` in `tests/`. Unittest's discovery only works on packages.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add these code in the beginning of yours:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.../common')
```

Or you can use absolute path in append.